# Как вызвать метод у дочернего компонента

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как вызвать метод у дочернего компонента из родительского ?

В родительском компоненте

```
<template>
    <show-modal :id="id"></show-modal>
    <button @click="id=1">ID</button>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
              id: '',
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

В дочернем компоненте будет вызвано модальное окно:

```
<template>
    <div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props:{
            id: '',
        },
        data() {
            return {
            }
        },
        methods:{
            ShowModal(id){
              if(id){
                $('#addNewUser').modal('show');
              }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Изпользуй $refs](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Для дочернего компонета прописываем

```
<show-modal ref="foobar" :id="id"></show-modal>
```

В родителе вызываем

```
this.$refs.foobar.ShowModal()
```